# Расположение окна программы в PyQt

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, pyqt5

Есть небольшая программа с установленным размером, нужно сделать так, чтобы при запуске ее окно открывалось в правом нижнем углу экрана, вплотную к краю справа и к панели задач снизу. Использую PyQt5. Вот отрывок кода:

```
def location_on_the_screen(self):
    fg = self.frameGeometry()
    sbrp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().bottomRight()
    fg.moveBottomRight(sbrp)
    self.move(fg.topLeft())
```

Но открывается таким образом программа немного за пределами экрана и справа, и снизу, уходя далеко за таскбар. В документации написано, что frameGeometry() возвращает размер вместе с рамкой окна, хотя у меня это не так, и из-за этого все криво. Прошу помощи. :)

Comment: не совсем идеальное решение, но после перемещения сделайте смещение влево вверх на нужное количество пикслей

Comment: такое решение не подходит, уже была такая идея...

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы точно разместить окно в правом нижнем углу, надо сначала отобразить окно, потом подвинуть. Чтобы исключить мелькание, нужно изначально сместить окно за рамки экрана:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget


def move2RightBottomCorner(win):
    screen_geometry = QApplication.desktop().availableGeometry()
    screen_size = (screen_geometry.width(), screen_geometry.height())
    win_size = (win.frameSize().width(), win.frameSize().height())
    x = screen_size[0] - win_size[0]
    y = screen_size[1] - win_size[1]
    win.move(x, y)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QWidget()
    w.move(w.width() * -3, 0) # чтобы не мелькало
    w.show()
    move2RightBottomCorner(w)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```